# Chmod by Letters Vs Numbers

Tags: chmod

I was recently asked by a colleague to use `chmod` with letters instead of numbers. Apart from the obvious readability advantage is there any particular reason to use letters over numbers ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `chmod` symbolic notation is more fine-grained compared to the octal notation, allowing the modification of specific mode bits while leaving other mode bits untouched.

The symbolic notation consists of three components:

```
chmod [references][operator][modes] file
```

The `references` consists of a combination of the letters `ugoa`, which specify which user's access to the `file` will be modified: the user who owns it (`u`), other users in the file's group (`g`), other users not in the file's group (`o`), or all users (`a`). If the `references` component is omitted, it defaults to all users, but only permissions allowed by the `umask` are modified.

The `+` `operator` causes the specified file mode bits to be added to the existing file mode bits of each file; `-` causes them to be removed; and `=` causes them to be added and unspecified bits to be removed, except `setuid` and `setgid` bits set for directories, unless explicitly specified.

The `mode` consists of a combination of the letters `rwxXst`, which correspond to the read (`r`), write (`w`), execute (or search for directories) (`x`), execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (`X`), `setuid` or `setgid` (depending on the specified references) (`s`) and restricted deletion flag or sticky bit (`t`). Alternatively, the `mode` can consist of one of the letters `ugo`, in which case case the `mode` corresponds to the permissions currently granted to the owner (`u`), member's of the file's group (`g`) or permssions of users in neither of the preceding categories (`o`).

**Examples**

Assuming the permission set for `file` is `0764/-rwxrw-r--`

Remove permission from other users not in file's group:

- Octal: `chmod 760 file`

  Note how the existing permissions left unchanged must be repeated when using the octal notation.
- Symbolic: `chmod o-rwx file`

  With symbolic notation, the existing file permissions do not matter.

Set `setuid`:

- Octal: `chmod 4764 file`
- Symbolic: `chmod u+s file`

Set `setgid`:

- Octal: `chmod 2764 file`
- Symbolic `chmod g+s file`

Answer (score 1):

Using the letters allows you to toggle individual bits on and off without changing the other bits.

Assume I have the following directory:

```
drwxrwsr-x   6 f261-01a  g261-01a  4096 Sep 12 17:51 /home/teams/261/f261-01a
```

If I want to turn off read permission for other and I want to use numbers, I might just
quickly do `chmod 751`.  Except I've just turned off the setgid bit on the directory.  Oops.

If, however, I use `chmod o-r`, I only toggle off the read bit I wanted and the setgid bit on the directory stays set.

It's also useful if you want to turn on setuid, setgid or sticky bits on a file or directory.  Especially if you do it so seldom you have trouble remembering which bit is which in the 4th octet.

So, it depends what you are doing.  I still prefer using numbers when I am just setting permissions and I don't care what is there to begin with.  But if you are toggling individual bits, the letter notation is much easier.