# How to copy permissions from owner to others using `chmod`?

Tags: chmod

Is it possible to recursively copy the permissions of owner to group and others for all files in a given directory?

PS: my `chmod` is 5.97

Comment: chmod -R $mode $path/ ?

Comment: the problem is not recursivety, is how to set $mode in a way that it would copy the owner permissions to group and others?

Comment: Do you know owner permission? if owner is 'rw' then it would be: chmod -R g=rwX $path/

Comment: this would imply manually check every file and then set the permissions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using [symbolic notation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94217/43779) in `chmod`:

```
chmod -R go=u /path/to/directory
```

Typically the mode specifiers following the operator consists of a combination of the letters `rwxXst`, each of which signifies the corresponding mode bit. However, the mode specifier may also consist of one of the letters `ugo`, in which case case the mode corresponds to the permissions currently granted to the owner (`u`), member's of the file's group (`g`) or permissions of users in neither of the preceding categories (`o`).

Comment: Wow. Didn't know about it, nice!