# How do I allow user permissions to data on a Couchpotato and Sickbeard Plugin using Freenas

Tags: permissions, freebsd, freenas, transmission

Trying to setup permissions for the plugins sickbeard / couchpotato.

I’ve read almost every thread google / the forums have but haven’t really found a solution yet.
I’m assuming it’s the data here: (Jail name)/usr/pbi/xxxxxxxxxx
I tried:

```
chown -R guest:guest /usr/pbi/sickbeard-amd64/*  
chown -R guest:guest /usr/pbi/couchpotato-amd64/*
```

But I couldn’t get it to work.
Or would I have to `chmod 777` the folders?

Comment: I'm closing this question as there is no information about what "does not work" means.

Answer (score 0):

You used `chown -R` to change the owner of the directory, but ultimately it's the permissions that matter, which are controlled by `chmod`. `chmod` details are explained more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94212/73).

Comment: chmod -R for folder and chmod for file

Comment: Re your comment: `chmod` will change the mode (permissions) on a file or a directory. The only thing `-R` adds is that if the target is a directory, then the contents will be changed too, recursively.